# Linux Mint doesn't recognize Disk

Tags: linux, linux-mint, system-installation, raid, disk

i have a lenovo ideapad s340 with win 10. When I install linux Mint the installer doesn't recognize the ssd. I found online that the problem is the sata Raid option . So i need to switch from Raid to AHCI. The problem is that i need the OEM recovery partition of the laptop (for the warranty), and when i switch a pop up says "the disk will be cleared, continue?". So, any method to prevent the disk cleaning? And also, should i backup the OEM in external hdd just in case?

Lenovo Ideapad s340 intel core i5 8265U win 10 Home

default safeboot ON (but i've tried also with off, the problem persist)

I just want the oem, not windows in dual boot (bc online i've found some dual boot tutorial, but i just want uninstall windows, and if i have some problems with Mint i want to be able to restore windows with the oem)

Thx everyone for the help =) sry for bad english